# Calling a method after two other methods have been completed

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am looking for the best standard javascript way of monitoring when a method is completed.

I have a method used for ajax calls like this:

```
function rdRelatedJobs(param1,param2,param3) {
    var completeURL = param1 + param2 + param3;

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:completeURL,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml){
            // We parse the XML here
                };
    },
        error: function() {
            console.log("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
        }
    });
} // end function rdRelatedJobs
```

This function is called twice, queued immediately after each other. What I need to know is how to call another method once the second call to this method is complete.

Note it does not matter if the ajax request is success or failure in this case. I just need to know how to call the method once the method above is run twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a jQuery-specific answer, and a general answer.

The jQuery-specific answer is to return the result of the `ajax` call, which is a `jqXHR` object:

```
function rdRelatedJobs(param1,param2,param3) {
    var completeURL = param1 + param2 + param3;

    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:completeURL,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml){
            // We parse the XML here
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
        }
    });

} // end function rdRelatedJobs
```

...and when you're calling `rdRelatedJobs`, use `$.when`:

```
$.when(
    rdRelatedJobs(/*...args for first call...*/),
    rdRelatedJobs(/*...args for second call...*/)
).then(function() {
    // both are done now
});
```

That works because `jqXHR` objects implement the jQuery `Promise` API, and `$.when` will call your callback when all of the promises you give it have been fulfilled.

The generic answer would be to use a promise library that does something similar.

Or another generic answer would be to have `rdRelatedJobs` call a callback when it's done, and to maintain a counter:

```
function rdRelatedJobs(param1,param2,param3,done) {
    var completeURL = param1 + param2 + param3;

    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:completeURL,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml){
            // We parse the XML here
            done(xml);
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
            done(null);
        }
    });
} // end function rdRelatedJobs
```

...and then:

```
var counter = 0;
function done(result) {
    if (--counter === 0) {
        // Both are done
    }
}
rdRelatedJobs(/*...args for first call...*/, done);
++counter;
rdRelatedJobs(/*...args for second call...*/, done);
++counter;
```

That looks like a race condition, but it isn't, because there is only one main UI JavaScript thread in browsers.

Comment: Thanks. I am interested more in the second approach. Because I do not care what is returned on the page JS, can I just call done()? Also... to note we have a main JS file which is loaded in the head, but the calls to the methods are made on the html page. The function done would also exists as in page JS if that matters at all?

Comment: I used a variant of the above. Just a callback on the method, then on the second call of the method in the callback I can call the third method this works and I do not need the counters. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
outside the function you can have a `var counter`
```

and then inside:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:completeURL,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml){
            // We parse the XML here
            counter++;
            if(counter==2) bla bla 
        };
    },
        error: function() {
            console.log("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
            counter++;
            if(counter==2) bla bla
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function rdRelatedJobs(param1,param2,param3) {
  var completeURL = param1 + param2 + param3;

  // return an ajax promise from this function
  return $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url:completeURL,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (xml) {
      // We parse the XML here
    },
    error: function () {
      console.log("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
    }
  });
}

// compile the promises by passing them into an array
function getPromises() {
  var promises = [];
  promises.push(rdRelatedJobs(1, 2, 3));
  promises.push(rdRelatedJobs(3, 4, 5));
  return promises;
}

// use $.when by passing in the promise array using the apply method
$.when.apply(null, getPromises()).then(function () {
  // do a thing
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a library called Q and do an 'all' and use a 'then' with a success and failure callback

https://github.com/kriskowal/q

e.g:

```
Q.all([rdRelatedJobs(x,y,z), rdRelatedJobs(a,b,c)]).then(function () {
    console.log("Data saved!");
});
```

Very similar to the jquery $.when the 'then' will only get called when both ajax requests have finished. You would have to alter the rdRelatedJobs to do a return just before the $.ajax so that the promise is returned from the function.